# Get maximum value from String Map in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using the following code

```
val maxEntries = myMap.values.max()?.let {
maxValue -> myMap.filterValues { it == maxValue }
} ?: emptyMap()
```

Working for values under 100, but 100 and above values it is picking the next highest value

Map:    `{0=65, 1=2, 2=100, 3=1, 4=11, 5=6, 6=46, 7=31}`

Max Value Print1: `{0=65}`

Another example:

Map: `{0=3, 1=3, 2=3, 3=3, 4=7, 5=6}`

Max Value Print2: `{4=7}`

I tried it this way too

```
val maxEntries = myMap.maxBy { it.value }?.value!!.toInt()
```

Print1: 65

Map is `HashMap<String, String>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you forgot to say that your values are of type `String`, not `Int` or `Long`. That's why they are compared as Strings (`b > a` and `b > abcgdf`, `6 > 1` so `6 > 10` or `6 > 1abcgfs` and `65 > 100`). When you want to compare strings as numbers you need to convert them to numbers or write comparator. If you are sure that these strings will be always numbers, just use

```
myMap.maxBy { it.value.toLong() }
// or for not very big numbers:
myMap.maxBy { it.value.toInt() }
```

or, when you need Int value at the end, maybe you should convert strings to numbers before this operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the max value whatever it is the key or the value, it should be:

```
myMap.maxBy { max(it.key.toInt(), it.value.toInt()) }
```